# GroupBy Linq with Where Criteria

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, where-clause

I have an object array like this;

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string URL {get; set;}
}
```

I got different Names but same URL addresses.
When I search with string array for Name criteria, I want to get distinct objects, where Name will be equal for same URLs.

For example:

```
var names = new List<Test>();
names.Add(new Test() { Name = "john", URL = "http://www.test.com" });
names.Add(new Test() { Name = "mark", URL = "http://www.test.com" });
names.Add(new Test() { Name = "john", URL = "http://www.test2.com" });
```

When i search for "john, mark" (includedWords) i want to get just one result for above example.

My test LINQ is like this but it fails;

```
var names = names.Select(n => new { URL = n.URL, Name = n.Name })
                 .GroupBy(o => o.URL)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() >= includedWords.Length)
                 .ToArray();
```

Any help would be save my day, thanks already!

Comment: is includedWords a single string or an array ?

Comment: I think it is typo, `()` with your class name.

Comment: Sorry for my missings, i have to leave office early so sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an array for `includedNames` :

```
var includedNames = new [] { "john", "mark" };
var result =  names
  .GroupBy(o => o.URL)
  .Where(g => g.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(n => n).SequenceEqual(includedNames))
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .ToArray();
```

If you get input as *string* in *comma-separated format* then just `Split` it.

Here is the [`fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAw5UR)

Comment: actually im using an array for includedNames so that will be no problem. I'll try this and give you reply as soon as possible :) thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on my needs such as i have to get object from that not key/value i changed your answer like this;

```
var result = names
             .Where(o => o.Select(p => p.Name).SequenceEqual(includedNames))
             .Select(g => g.First())
             .ToArray();
```

Thanks for all of your help!